# Maven Compiling After Eclipse Clean Only

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using Eclipse Mars 4.5.1, Maven 3.0.5, and Java 8.  If I do the following:

- Eclipse Clean
- `mvn compile`

Maven compiles fine.

However if I run `mvn clean compile` I get a lot of errors that that don't make sense such as:

```
[ERROR] /home/ole/Sandbox/math/firefly-math-linear-real/src/main/java/com/fireflysemantics/math/linear/exceptions/LinearExceptionFactory.java:[23,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   static MATRIX_DIMENSION_MISMATCH__OPERATE
[ERROR] location: class
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Well, is `MATRIX_DIMENSION_MISMATCH__OPERATE` defined? Could you post `LinearExceptionFactory` code? "Eclipse Clean" is completely different than a Maven clean.

Comment: Try to switch off automatic eclipse build. It may conflict with maven build.

Comment: This is the repository: https://github.com/firefly-math/firefly-math-linear-real

Comment: Link to LinearExceptionFactory: https://github.com/firefly-math/firefly-math-linear-real

Comment: I just realized what is going on.  I've been updating both the exception module and the linear module independently.  Eclipse sees all the updates and creates keeps the dependencies current, but Maven had no way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my local dependencies was not current in the Maven repository.  Once I compiled it things worked fine.  Thanks for helping me think through it guys.

Ole